# Angular - How to add new component (with separate fields) to webform

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webforms

I am creating classifieds site on Angular.

Route "add" has two components:

1) for categories (onInit -> recieved from database);

2) for subcategories (after selected category -> recieved list of subcategories from database);

and separate router-outlet.

In router-outlet I recieved selected subcategory "id", but I can't understand how to include required component with all fields for selected sudcategory.

Maybe I am wrong and there is another way how to solve this task?

Here my code:

**main root component for route "add" addadvert.component.html**

```
<app-adcat [categors]="categors" (selectCat)="selectCat($event)"></app-adcat>
<app-adsubcat [subcategors]="subcategors" (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"></app-adsubcat>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**adcat.component.html**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h3>Select category</h3>
</div>
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let categor of categors">
  <li class="list-group-item" (click)="select(categor)" [class.selected]="categor === selected">{{ categor.cat_name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**adsubcat.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="subcategors">
  <div class="page-header">
  <h3>Select subcategory</h3>
</div>
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let subcat of subcategors; let i = index">
  <li class="list-group-item" (click)="select(subcat)" [class.selected]="subcat === selected" >{{ subcat.subcat_name }}</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

**adsubcat.component.ts**

```
select(subcat) {
  this.selected = subcat;
  this._router.navigate(["add/selected", subcat.id_subcat]);
}
```

**route add/selected/id**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._activatedRoute.params.forEach(params => {
  this.selectedSubCat = params;
 })
}
```

I have a solution, but it's not very elegant:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedSubCat.id === '1'">
  <app-rent></app-rent>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedSubCat.id === '2'">
  <app-sell></app-sell>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question as it stands is not clear enough. Please add the relevant code to make the context more understandable. See [ask]

Comment: Either store the complete object (I assume it is) in a shared service, or then upon navigation retrieve that single object from the backend based on id (if you have that possibility). For further help you really need to provide code to be able to help you.